# Vim: Edit multi aleatory lines

Tags: vim

I'm aware of the possibility to edit multiple lines on the same column by doing:

```
CTRL+V down...down..down... SHIFT+I type_string_wanted
```

But I'd like to edit multiple specific locals addin new strings (maybe using cursor (h j k l) or mouse (with :set mouse=a)).

Like on this example, where I want to add the string 'XX' to specific locations. I.e.,

from this:

```
Hi.
My name is Mario!
```

to this:

```
XXHi.
My XXname is XXMario!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As long as you're going to have to manually select each location anyway, is there some reason you don't want to just edit the first location, then use `.` to do the same at each other?

Comment: @Jefromi I got your point. But it's also related to apprenticeship, and know if is there a way to do it. And, for another reason, it could be for the visual aspect of seeming it change the visual appearance of all places at once.

Comment: @Jefromi I got your point again. And think it solves my desire. Could you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: I do see what you mean - it's pretty cool to see it happen all at once, and sometimes it's more intuitive to us to think of locations before actions. I just don't think there's any way to actually do that, so I thought I'd be pragmatic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the first location and then use `.` to repeat the action at each additional location.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reverse the order of your steps.

Instead of marking each location, then performing the change on all at once, just edit the first location, then use `.` to do the same to each of the others.

This doesn't add any keystrokes to your use case; instead of hitting some key to mark a spot beforehand, you hit `.` afterward.

If you suspect you might accidentally do some other things in between usages, you could record a macro using `q<register>` the first time, and play it back with `@<register>` each of the others.